# Online youtube music player

Tags: flash, youtube, mpmusicplayercontroller

Does anyone knows the htm/flash code which acts like music plyer using youtube video?

Answer (score 0):

[Songza](http://songza.org/) uses youtube and iMeem videos as music, and lets you make playlists and stuff, but I think they just dynamically embed the videos and control them.

Comment: I thinj of somthing you can embed on your own page